# mongoDB can't createCollection() nodejs?

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I am using mongoose with node.js, I have a file called models.js where I define my schema then export them.

```
module.exports = {
    Team   : mongoose.model('Team', Team),
    Player : mongoose.model('Player', Player)
};
```

When I want to query the DB I run commands like

```
models.Team.find({}, function(err, teams) {
    console.log(teams); // this lists all the teams just fine, function works
});
```

But I am trying to create a new collection so I can save my Players collection into a new one then clear the collection. So I am trying the below and I get `has no method 'createCollection'`

```
models.Player.createCollection('week1');
```

I have also tried the below, not really sure how to define my target lol but I have used robo mongo to create a collection called `test`

```
models.Player.copyTo('test')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With Mongoose, the model is the name of the collection. You can override it, but are you sure you want a different collection for each week? Mongo collections are similar to tables in the rdbms world. You probably would not want a new table for each week.

Comment: Yeah I agree, this never sounded optimal to me, but I need to store data from week 1 somewhere then clear the stats for week 2 use, so that in the future I can still refer to the past. Any suggestions on how I should store this data? I would like to make requests to a specific week, so storing it on the computer would not be an option.

Comment: Maybe I can create one collection called playersByWeek or something like that and create an array? That would be a pain client side with backbone.js but that may work? ex. `{player_name: 'Michael', [{date: 'week_1', points: 7}, {date: 'week_2', points: 22}]}`

Comment: I guess I could make a schema for that, then populate it by date or something of the sort. Like `models.Players.find({}, function(err, player) { var player = new PlayersWeekly({ player_name: player.player_name}), stats: [{date: week_1, points: 7}] })` Then somehow I can push into the `stats` array?

Comment: @MichaelJosephAubry why not simply filter the collection by week by player?

Comment: Wow I know this is way past due, but I think I may have to somehow incorporate a smart date system then. What happens is in real time as the game is being played the person taking stats is literally clicking on a player model and adding 2 points or whatever stat to the server via POST throughout the whole game. There are 8 games each night, and when all of them are tracked and shared to facebook I want to save all the models etc into a separate batch, so that next weeks game is fresh. I just don't know how I can associate a date with that?

Comment: @MichaelJosephAubry you could treat each event as its own document, timestamping all the while, and use aggregations to group the data back together. Also, you could have a daily job that moves documents to another collection.

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this is like this:

Make a method that takes as arguments the collection's name and the collection's model,
and returns the mongoose model that corresponds to the given collection name and model. 
for example:

```
function createCollection (collectionName, model) {
    return mongoose.model(collectionName, model);
}
```

Then you could use the `createCollection` function to get seperate collections using the same schema. For example:

Considering that you have defined the Player's schema like this:

```
var playerSchema = {
    name: String
};
```

You could get a collection for week 1 players, and a separate collection for week 2 players like this ( you could extend it to as many collections you want, or to collections for fixed time periods i.e. weekly etc, according to your needs ):

```
var Player_week_1 = createCollection('week_1_player', playerSchema);

var Player_week_2 = createCollection('week_2_player', playerSchema);
```

To summarize, the following working code shows how it can be done:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/test');

function createCollection (collectionName, model) {
    return mongoose.model(collectionName, model);
}

var playerSchema = {
    name: String
};

var Player_week_1 = createCollection('week_1_player', playerSchema);
var Player_week_2 = createCollection('week_2_player', playerSchema);

var playerA = new Player_week_1( { name: 'playerA-week-1'});
playerA.save(function (error) {
    if (error) {
        console.log('error saving playerA in week_1_players');
    } else {
        console.log('saved playerA in week_1_players');
    }
});

var playerB = new Player_week_2( { name: 'playerB-week-2'});
playerB.save(function (error) {
    if (error) {
        console.log('error saving playerB in week_2_players');
    } else {
        console.log('saved playerB in week_2_players');
    }
});
```